# In asp.net-mvc, what is the best way to return a partial view as well as other data from an ajax call?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a regular ajax call where the server side returns a partial view (html).  I now have a situation where i need the server to passback some additional data besides the partial view.  The only thought i had was to change the return to json and shove the partial view HTML into a json field but that seemed hacky.

Is there anyway to return a partial view from the server as well as other some other info?

Comment: It depends who will consume that data. You can use the response header, for example.

Comment: I found this site that seems to indicate this approach is not so crazy:http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this solution that seems to do the job: http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/